# Usage information garbled when printed to pdf or printer

Tags: bugs, printing, information-function

**Seems to be fixed in version 11.0**

In *Mathematica* v10.2 running in the notebook `Information`

```
?Integrate
```

yields the following

[image]

But, when printed to printer or pdf, the spacing gets messed up:

[image]

This affects usage messages for all symbols (built-in and user-defined).
What can I do to get around this issue when printed?  Also, is this issue solved in version 10.3.1?

Comment: With v10.3.1 on my Mac, `Print...` still has this problem with spacing; but, `Save As... | PDF Document (*.pdf)` has correct spacing. However, `Save As... | PDF Document (*.pdf)` with v10.2 crashes Mathematica and produces a document which cannot be opened with my PDFpenPro.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: Yes, Confirmed on 10.3.1 mac as well

Comment: What is the status of this bug in 10.4.1?

Comment: I'm using 10.4 and it doesn't have this problem (both Save as and Print). Why don't you use the Save as ... | PDF option ?